# Pandas sum-lag of a column

Tags: pandas

Lets say I have the data like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"MONTHS":[1,2,3,4,5,6], "METRIC":[430,584,648,571,610,535]})
```

df = pd.DataFrame({"MONTHS":[1,2,3,4,5,6], "METRIC":[430,584,648,571,610,535]})
what I want to do is find the sum of the metric column =3378

```
MONTHS NEW_METRIC
 0       3378
 1       3378
 2       2948
 3       2794
 4       2730
 5       2807
 6       2768
```

So here basically created a new row with 0 added and the corresponding new metric is the sum and for value 1 it is also the sum for new metric but from month=2 it should subtract the lag value of metric (3378-430) and similiarly for months3 it would be (3378-584) etc till the end. 
As a first step I wanted to store the sum in result which failed

```
sum_METRIC = df.agg({"METRIC":"sum"}).collect()[0]
result = sum_METRIC["sum(METRIC)"]
```

This threw error 'Series' object has no attribute 'collect'.

How do I sum and then use the lag to subtract?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can substract METRIC for the resulting sum:

```
In [11]: df["METRIC"].sum() - df["METRIC"].reindex(np.arange(0, 7)).shift(2).fillna(0)
Out[11]:
0    3378.0
1    3378.0
2    2948.0
3    2794.0
4    2730.0
5    2807.0
6    2768.0
Name: METRIC, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Not sure if you need `reindex`.

Comment: @QuangHoang without the reindex you don't start at MONTHS 0, which is in the OPs expected. But yeah, maybe not necessary...

Comment: I thought `reindex` for adding an additional row as OP wants. Besides `reindex`, are there other shorter ways to create an additional row?

Comment: @AndyHayden- Thanks- but Is there a way to dynamically  say the df length instead of 7 (length+1)?

Comment: @viji np.arange(df.MONTHS.iloc[0] - 1, df.MONTHS.iloc[-1])

Comment: @AndyHayden thanks just realised that instead of 7-replacing with len(df)+1 also worked

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
df['New']=df["METRIC"].sum() - np.array([0,0]+df["METRIC"].tolist())[:len(df)]
df
Out[307]: 
   MONTHS  METRIC   New
0       1     430  3378
1       2     584  3378
2       3     648  2948
3       4     571  2794
4       5     610  2730
5       6     535  2807
```